# $(\dim_K\ker f)^2 + (\dim_K\operatorname{im} f)^2 = (\dim_K X )^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

So I have $X$, $Y$ vector spaces over a field $K$ and $f : X\to Y$ linear operator.

The problem asks me to define $\ker f$. Next, it says that given

$(\dim_K\ker f)^2 + (\dim_K\operatorname{im} f)^2 = (\dim_K X)^2$ and $\dim_K\ker f \neq 0$

I must show that $\dim_K\operatorname{im} f = 0$

Any ideas?

Comment: "Field" is the correct term for $K$

Comment: Note that by the [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem), we have
$$
\dim_K \ker f + \dim_K \operatorname{im} f = \dim_K X
$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I formatted your question removing your comment about body being field, and changed it accordingly (you were correct). Hope this is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Rank-Nullility Theorem:
$$\dim_K \ker f + \dim_K \operatorname{im} f = \dim_K X\tag{1}$$
Now 
$$(\dim_K\ker f)^2 + (\dim_K\operatorname{im} f)^2 = (\dim_K X)^2\tag{2}$$
and $\dim_K\ker f \neq 0$. Leting $\dim_K \ker f=a$, $\dim_K \operatorname{im} f =b$, and $\dim_K X=c$, for some $a$, $b$, $c\in\Bbb{Z}_{\ge0}$then by $(1)$,
$$a+b=c\tag{3}$$
But by $(2)$,
$$a^2+b^2=c^2\tag{4}$$

The question then is: is $(4)$ possible in light of $(3)$ with $b\neq0$.

By $(3)$ you get
$$a^2=c^2-2bc+b^2\tag{5}$$
By $(4)$ you get
$$a^2=c^2-b^2\tag{6}$$
So by $(5)$ and $(6)$
$$c^2-2bc+b^2=c^2-b^2\implies b^2=bc$$
or $b=c$, which is impossible by $(3)$ as $\dim_K\ker f =a>0$, and so we must have $\dim_K \operatorname{im} f=b=0$ as required.

Comment: This is really comprehensive, thanks!

Comment: My pleasure, cheers :)

Answer (score 3):

Since by rank-nullity theorem

dim(ker $f)+$dim(im $f$) $=$ dim($X)$.

Squaring both sides yields

dim(ker $f$) $\cdot$ dim(im $f)=0$,

but
dim(ker $f$) is nonzero so dim(im $f) =0.$

Comment: Thanks for the answer!